# React.js / Next.js - how to link from one article to another?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Suppose this example with two articles (full example here https://github.com/codebushi/nextjs-starter-dimension/blob/master/components/Main.js)

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {

    let close = <div className="close" onClick={() => {this.props.onCloseArticle()}}></div>

    return (
      <div id="main" style={this.props.timeout ? {display: 'flex'} : {display: 'none'}}>

        <article id="intro" className={`${this.props.article === 'intro' ? 'active' : ''} ${this.props.articleTimeout ? 'timeout' : ''}`} style={{display:'none'}}>
          <h2 className="major">Intro</h2>
          <span className="image main"><img src="/static/images/pic01.jpg" alt="" /></span>
          <p>Nam maximus erat id euismod egestas. By the way, check out my <a href="#work">awesome work</a>.</p>
          {close}
        </article>

        <article id="work" className={`${this.props.article === 'work' ? 'active' : ''} ${this.props.articleTimeout ? 'timeout' : ''}`} style={{display:'none'}}>
          <h2 className="major">Work</h2>
          <span className="image main"><img src="/static/images/pic02.jpg" alt="" /></span>
          <p>Adipiscing magna sed dolor elit. Praesent eleifend dignissim arcu, at eleifend sapien imperdiet ac. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent urna nisi, fringila lorem et vehicula lacinia quam. Integer sollicitudin mauris nec lorem luctus ultrices.</p>
          {close}
        </article>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

Main.propTypes = {
  route: PropTypes.object,
  article: PropTypes.string,
  articleTimeout: PropTypes.bool,
  onCloseArticle: PropTypes.func,
  timeout: PropTypes.bool
}

export default Main
```

How do I create a link in the `intro` article to open the `work` article? In the example there's an `<a href='#work'>`, but when I click it there's no action at all.

Comment: It doesn't work like that, you should use a package like react navigation. `npm i react-navigation`, and site: [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by importing 'Link' from Next.js:

```
import Link from "next/link";
```

Then you can add:

```
    <Link href="work">
          <a>Go To Work!</a>
    </Link>
```

Full documentation from Next.js: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link

Comment: Did you end up finding the answer or would it be helpful for me to edit this question?

Comment: for this case in specific it doesn't seem to work. I think because of how the app is structured - the navigation doesn't seem as simple as that. When I use your solution I get a 404, as the generated link takes me to /try, and it seems like I would need to close the current article and open the other one in order for this to work.

pages/index.js has methods for that, but I know pretty much nothing of React yet, so don't know how to do it.